Unable to detect if a image is blurred in few cases
I have used OpenCvSharp for the first time. I'm using it to find out if an image is blurred or not. Some of the images are blurred but my code is returning that the image is not blurred. Attached images for reference. Please review my code and let me know if I have used OpenCvSharp correctly
public static bool IsBlurry(string imagePath, double threshold = 100.0)
{
    // Load the image
    var image = Cv2.ImRead(imagePath, ImreadModes.Grayscale);
    
    // Compute the Laplacian of the image
    var laplacian = new Mat();
    Cv2.Laplacian(image, laplacian, MatType.CV_64F);

    // Compute the variance of Laplacian
    Cv2.MeanStdDev(laplacian, out _, out var stddev);

    var varianceValue = stddev.Val0 * stddev.Val0; // Variance = standard deviation squared

    // Check if the image is blurred
    return varianceValue < threshold;
}

Thanks in advance.




Are you normalizing the size of the images?

No, I'm not. All the code that detects the blurriness is part of the question.

the issue is bokeh, which is a lowpass, but each circle has a "sharp" border, which represents high frequency content.

The simple answer is that there is no simple way to detect if an image is blurry or not. This filter will also say that a perfectly in focus picture of mist is out of focus. The fact is that “blurry” is a relative measure. Take two images of the same scene, this algorithm (or any of the many other similar ones) will tell you which one is more blurry. If you can’t compare, you have to make assumptions about the contents of the image. These three images break the assumptions that this algorithm makes.

On a pic of bokeh, a corner detector would strike out. All the high freq features are edges (on circles or aperture-shaped things), but not corners.
